# My emacs installation does not initialise

Tags: org-mode, init-file, package

I don't know what happened but now I cannot initialise my emacs installation. emacs --debug-init gives this answer:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Unable to activate package ‘org-ac’.
Required package ‘auto-complete-pcmp-0.0.1’ is unavailable")
  signal(error ("Unable to activate package ‘org-ac’.\nRequired package ‘auto-complete-pcmp-0.0.1’ is unavailable"))
  error("Unable to activate package `%s'.\nRequired package `%s-%s' is unavailable" org-ac auto-complete-pcmp "0.0.1")
  package-activate-1([cl-struct-package-desc org-ac (20140302 413) "Some auto-complete sources for org-mode" ((auto-complete-pcmp (0 0 1)) (log4e (0 2 0)) (yaxception (0 1))) nil nil "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/elpa/org-ac-20140302.413" ((:keywords "org" "completion") (:url . "https://github.com/aki2o/org-ac")) nil] nil deps)
  package-activate(org-ac)
  package-initialize()
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 403
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\266   \306=\203\307\310Q\202? \311=\204\307\312Q\202?\313\307\314\315#\203*\316\202?\313\307\314\317#\203>\320\321\322!D\nB\323\202?\316\324\325\324\211#\210\324=\203e\326\327\330\307\331Q!\"\325\324\211#\210\324=\203d\210\203\247\332!\333\232\203\247\334!\211\335P\336!\203\201\211\202\214\336!\203\213\202\214\314\262\203\245\337\"\203\243\340\341#\210\342\343!\210\266\f?\205\264\314\325\344\324\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" initialization format-message "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'" "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: Bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to install a new package, and it has a dependency that your config doesn't know anything about.  Do `M-x package-refresh-contents` and then try again. If that fails, I guess you can't use that `org-ac` package after all (or you'll have to revert to your previous working version, if it's something you were already using).

Answer (score 1):

Reading the error message the required package [auto-complete-pcmp](https://github.com/aki2o/auto-complete-pcmp) seems to be not installed.

A possible way to fix that, is:

1/ restart emacs without loading your `init.el` file. Under the shell type:

```
emacs -q &
```

2/ Under Emacs (I assumed that you use package.el), go to the *Scratch* buffer and enter

```
(package-initialize)
(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
```

then <kbd>M-x eval-buffer</kbd>

3/ then you can access to your package-list etc. as usual. Type <kbd>M-x package-list-packages</kbd> and reinstall `auto-complete-pcmp`

4/ quit Emacs <kbd>C-x</kbd> and restart it as usual.

Comment: When I type `M-x package-list-packages` I can't find `auto-complete-pcmp`. But I see this package in [link](https://melpa.org/#/?q=auto-complete-pcmp).

Comment: @sbac even after `M-x package-refresh-contents` ?

Comment: Yes, even after `M-x package-refresh-contents`. But I got a message: `Failed to download 'gnu' archive`.

Comment: That is strange, you define: `(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))` ? Maybe try to restart Emacs with `emacs -Q` instead of `emacs -q` in step 1/. Besides that, I have no other idea, sorry.

Comment: Finally, it is solved. I used the code I copied from Melpa.org: `(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
                    (not (gnutls-available-p))))
       (url (concat (if no-ssl "http" "https") "://melpa.org/packages/")))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa" url) t))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line`

Comment: @sbac Happy that you solved the problem, thanks for the feedback.